# Python frequency of 2D array

Tags: list

I want to see the frequency of the data for each year.

My array looks like this : List[Data,Year]

List[[259,1910],[259,1910],[259,1910],[192,1910].....

```
Data Year
259  1910
259  1910
259  1910
192  1910
313  1910
259  1911
259  1911
192  1912
313  1912
```

I want to get the result like

```
Data Year Frequency
259  1910     3
259  1911     2
259  1912     0
192  1910     1
192  1911     0
192  1912     1
...
```

..
.

Comment: What have you already tried ?

Comment: You might try a hash. Please post your code to get more responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary to count frequency. Python allows using tuple as dictionary key.

```python
data = [259, 259, 192, 313, 259, 259, 192, 313]
yrs = [1910, 1910, 1910, 1910, 1911, 1911, 1912, 1912]
frequencies = {}
for idx in range(len(data)):
    key = (data[idx], yrs[idx])
    if key in frequencies:
        frequencies[key] += 1
    else:
        frequencies[key] = 1
data_with_freq = []
for key, freq in frequencies.iteritems():
    print (key[0], key[1], freq)
    data_with_freq.append((key[0], key[1], freq))
```

Comment: my list is 2d and does not look like yours

Comment: The idea is to use dictionary, the input data structure is quite irrelevant.